# Приложение и определяемое слово

Tags: синтаксис

В предложении: "Выдра Эммет очень красива" - почему-то главное слово "выдра", а Эммет - приложение. Хотя есть же правило, что если встречаются одушевленное существительное и нарицательное приложение, то приложением будет являться последнее (или это правило касалось только одушевленных существительных, называющих имена и фамилии)?

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить такую информацию:

"*В сочетании **имени человека и его характеристики** главным словом является имя, фамилия, прозвище человека. Характеристика (указание на возраст, специальность, родство и пр.) является приложением. Терапевт Комаров, вождь Большая Нога, дедушка Тимофей. Если речь идёт **о животных**, всё наоборот: кличка животного является **приложением**, а название вида — определяемым словом. Пёс Тузик, слониха Матильда".*

[Согласованные и несогласованные приложения](https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/soglasovannye-i-nesoglasovannye-prilozheniya.html#:%7E:text=%D0%92%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B8,%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Почему так?  **С точки зрения семантики** определяемым (главным) словом для человека является его **имя**, а для животного — видовое наименование (оно передает основное содержание).